# OpenTok install API

Tags: php, ubuntu, api, https, apache2

Есть сервис видеопотоков OpenTok.

Пробовала установить их API на свой сервер ubuntu.
Всё делала по примеру https://github.com/opentok/learning-opentok-php

Запустила composer, который удачно всё установил. 
При запуске run-demo выходит ошибка
`You must define an TOKBOX_API_KEY and TOKBOX_SECRET in the run-demo file`
Хотя в самом файле всё это прописано.
Пример файла.

```
if [ -z "$TOKBOX_API_KEY" ] || [ -z "$TOKBOX_SECRET" ]
then
  export API_KEY=ТутКлючСсайта
  export API_SECRET=ТутСикретСсайта
fi

if [ -d "storage" ]
then
  rm -rf storage/
fi

php -S мойсайт.ru:8080 -t web/
```

Мне необходимо поднять API OpenTok на сервере https.
В apache2 прописала путь к папке:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName мойсайт.ру
        DocumentRoot /var/www/Project/opentok/web/
        <Directory "/var/www/Project/opentok/web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
        </Directory>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/temp.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/temp.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/temp_ca.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

В /var/www/Project лежит скаченный и установленный https://github.com/opentok/learning-opentok-php

Запускается страница с описанием методов API, но когда вызываю любой метод, например мойсайт.ру/session - пишет, что такого файла нет =(

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

Файл htaccess который лежит рядом с файлом index.php из OpenTok learning

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Вот папка со скаченным и установленным
https://github.com/opentok/learning-opentok-php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Папка web, которая внутри.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как корректно прописать доступ к API на сервере?

Comment: Запуск через run-demo будет создавать и привязывать процесс к локальному серверу (localhost), а не через Apache. Даже поменяв его там с localhost на мойсайт.ру вы не добъетесь нужного результата. Вам нужно убедиться что вы настроили сервер Apache для доступа к нему извне по заданному в конфигурации домену мойсайт.ру. Для того чтобы переменные были доступны для сервера, их можно экспортировать через export, либо, что лучше, задать их в [/etc/apache2/envvars](https://medium.com/@william.b/setting-dynamic-environmental-variables-in-apache-from-the-os-1d5c1e2e9e6c).

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Да, Вы абсолютно правы относительно  run-demo. Честно говоря уже четвёртые сутки бьюсь, уже всё перепробовала. Если Вам не сложно, подскажите пожалуйста как мне правильно прописать эти параметры? Ещё я пробовала прописать доступ к отдельной папке установленной с  https://github.com/opentok/learning-opentok-php В apache, как в примере прописала доступ к файлу web/index.php, но выходит ошибка `The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.` Не могу понять, что я не так делаю . Помогите пожалуйста 

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Папка с learning-opentok-php располагается в /var/www/opentok/ Там есть файлы стандартные с run-demo и так далее и папка web. В ней файл index.php. В apache пробовала и к нему доступ прописать и просто к папке, но всегда одна и даже ошибка которую написала в предыдущем комментарии. Радом с файлом index.php лежит htaccess. Когда его отключаю - загружается страница с описанием методов, но ни один метод не работает, пишет ошибку `Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server` Файл htaccess добавила в описание вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вся установка описана для локальной машины.**

0. Клонирование проекта в папку:
   `git clone git@github.com:opentok/learning-opentok-php.git /var/www/`
1. Установка Apache и включение модуля rewrite через `sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php && sudo a2enmod rewrite`
2. Установка php-cli
   `sudo apt install php-cli`
3. Установка ext-curl для PHP:
   `sudo apt install php-curl`
4. Установка Composer:
   `sudo apt install composer`
5. Установка пакетов composer:
   `cd /var/www/learning-opentok-php && composer install`
6. Установке переменных в /etc/apache2/envvars:

   `export TOKBOX_API_KEY=0000000`

   `export TOKBOX_SECRET=abcdef1234567890abcdef01234567890abcdef`
7. /etc/apache2/sites-available/tok.conf:

   ````
   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName tok

      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
      DocumentRoot /var/www/learning-opentok-php/web
      <Directory "/var/www/learning-opentok-php/web">
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      </Directory>

      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
   </VirtualHost>```
   ````
8. Ссылка в /etc/apache2/sites-enabled на tok.conf:

   `sudo ln -s ../sites-available/tok.conf`
9. Владение папки как www-data т.к. Apache по-умолчанию работает с ней:

   `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/learning-opentok-php/`
10. [Проверка Firewall (ufw)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-ubuntu-18-04-ru):
    `sudo ufw app list`
11. [Перезапуск apache2 и проверка статуса](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-ubuntu-18-04-ru)

`sudo systemctl restart apache2`

`sudo systemctl status apache2`

Финал: по адресу http://tok/room/session выбрасывает ошибку потому что у меня нет ключа и токена.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!!! Это очень помогло. 
Единственное, надо было ещё в app.json добавить ключ и secret.
Спасибо Вам огромное за помощь!!! Всё получилось. Очень признательна.